# Get order of list items in a jQuery Sortable list after resort

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list on my website. I'm using jQuery's sortable tutorial to give users the ability to change the order of the list items.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

The trick is I would like to capture the order of the items immediately after a resort and assign the order values to hidden form elements which would be passed to my server via a form-submit where I could use a php script to save the new order of elements in a database.

Here's the source code of the demo:

```
 <style>
    #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
    #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
    #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    });
    </script>


<div class="demo">

<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

And I'm aware that it's also possible to assign a call-back function that fires when sorting stops:

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
   stop: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

*I wrote an answer to this question 5 years ago, but that answer sucked (and this question has almost 38,000 views), so here's an improved answer.*

There's essentially three parts of this question that you have to solve. We'll look at all three.

#### Responding to changes in the sort order (Step 1)

The first issue we need to solve is reacting to changes in the order of sorted elements. If we check out the jQuery UI Sortable Widget's [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/), we see that it has a [`change`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-change) event which fires whenever the sort order changes, and is perfect for our needs.

> Side note: My original answer used `stop` instead of the `change` event. `change` is better (at least in this case) because it will report all changes in sorting, whether the change was interactive (user) or programmatic, and only if the order has actually changed. On the other hand, the `sort` event is only fired when the user stops sorting (releases the mouse, or lifts their finger).

Using the `sort` event, we can now respond to changes in sorting. The following will initialize a `Sortable` widget for us, and allow us to set a function to be called when the `sort` even fires:

```js
var $sortableList = $("#your-list");

var sortEventHandler = function(event, ui){
    console.log("New sort order!");
};

$sortableList.sortable({
    stop: sortEventHandler
});

// You can also set the event handler on an already existing Sortable widget this way:

$sortableList.on("sortchange", sortEventHandler);
```

With that done, we're now ready to take on step 2:

#### Retrieving the sorted elements (Step 2)

This part is fairly simple. We just need to get an array of the elements in our sorted list. To do this, we can just ask for the children of the `ul` (list) element, using the jQuery function `children()`:

```
var listElements = $sortableList.children();

console.log(listElements); // [ <li>, <li>, ... ]
```

Great, but we specifically need the element's values:

```
var listValues = [];

listElement.forEach(function(element){
    listValues.push(element.innerHTML);
});

console.log(listValues); // [ "Item 1", "Item 2", ... ]
```

Using [`.sortable("toArray")`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray) or [`.serialize()`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) are also options.

Nice! On to the final bit.

#### Serializing & sending off the new sorted order (Step 3)

Serialization is "the process of translating data structures or object state into a format that can be stored (for example, in a file or memory buffer, or transmitted across a network connection link)" (thanks [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)!)

How you do this depends a lot on your specific needs, so we'll just discuss some of the ways you could get it done using jQuery.

**AJAX:**

If we use AJAX, we can just shoot off a request to the server with the new order. jQuery will automatically handle serializing `listValues` for us:

```
$.post("your-server.com/save_order", { "items": listValues } );
```

Or if you prefer JSON:

```
$.post("your-server.com/save_order", JSON.encode({ "items": listValues }) );
```

**Form**

Create a form:

```
<form action="your-server.com/save_order" method="POST">
    <input name="items" value="" />
</form>
```

Update the `item` input:

```
var serializedValue = $.param(listValues);

$("#ourForm > input").val(JSON.encode(listValues));
```

Send it:

```
$("#ourForm").submit()
```

#### Old answer:

HTML:

```
<form action="save_order.php" method="POST" style="display: none;">
<input name="new_order" value="" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".selector").sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var data = "";

        $("#sortable li").each(function(i, el){
            var p = $(el).text().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
            data += p+"="+$(el).index()+",";
        });

        $("form > [name='new_order']").val(data.slice(0, -1));
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
```

And in save_order.php, you can parse the POST variable "new_order" and get the orders of Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, etc.

Comment: Please can you explain this answer rather than just pasting code.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ I rewrote this answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Your "Step 2" is the part I was interested in (and I think the OP too).  I initially found it strange that the newly sorted element order was not made available in any of the fired events.  The [official docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-sort) go on about the old and new positions, but only as useless top & left pixel values.  **The library itself manipulates the element positions inside of the DOM for you, so doing a simple jquery selector in the event handler will give you the new order.**

Comment: hey @mattsven i am new to jquery... can you please provide jsfiddel for this because i am finding difficulty to understand this

Comment: What parts are you having trouble with specifically?

Answer (score 12):

Try using `serialize` to format a string to send to your database update script.

http://jsfiddle.net/zFQ2j/

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#method-serialize

Answer (score 9):

May this helps:

```
alert($( "#sortable" ).sortable( "toArray" ).toSource());
```

Comment: You need to have an `id` attribute on your `li`s or specific another attribute like `alert($( "#sortable" ).sortable( "toArray", {attribute: 'data-item_number'} ).toSource());` for this to work.

Comment: Relevant answer to elements without IDs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15382832/4907950

Answer (score 6):

> May, 2018

This Javascript example will give you all list of DIVS in #sortableContainer each time sorting is done

```
<div id="sortableContainer">
   <div id="Element1" class="sortIt">Item 1</div>
   <div id="Element2" class="sortIt">Item 2</div>
   <div id="Element3" class="sortIt">Item 3</div>
   <div id="Element4" class="sortIt">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$( function() {
  $( "#sortableContainer" ).sortable({

    stop: function(event, ui) {

      var itemOrder = $('#sortableContainer').sortable("toArray");

      for (var i = 0; i < itemOrder.length; i++) {
        console.log("Position: " + i + " ID: " + itemOrder[i]);
      }

    }
  });

});
```

DEMO and Credits:
http://www.tutorialspark.com/jqueryUI/jQuery_UI_Sortable_Getting_Order_of_Sortable.php

Answer (score 0):

Easy to solve:

```js
jQuery_2( function() {
 var url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>planner/Planner/edit_status/';
 jQuery_2('ul[id^="sort"]').sortable({
     connectWith: ".sortable",
     /*receive: function (e, ui) {
         var status_id = jQuery_2(ui.item).parent(".sortable").data("status-id");
         var task_id = jQuery_2(ui.item).data("task-id");
         jQuery_2.ajax({
             url: url,
             method: 'POST',
             data: { status_id: status_id, task_id: task_id, },
             success: function(response){ }
         });
    },*/
    update: function(e, ui) {
        var status_id = jQuery_2(ui.item).parent(".sortable").data("status-id");
        var task_id = jQuery_2(ui.item).data("task-id");
        var order_id = jQuery_2(ui.item).index();
        jQuery_2.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: { status_id: status_id, task_id: task_id, order_id: order_id, },
            success: function(response){ }
        });
    }

 }).disableSelection();
 } );
```

var order_id = jQuery_2(ui.item).index(); // Get order

Answer (score 0):

And you can:

```js
jQuery_2( function() {
 var url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>planner/Planner/edit_status/';
 jQuery_2('ul[id^="sort"]').sortable({
     connectWith: ".sortable",
     /*receive: function (e, ui) {
         var status_id = jQuery_2(ui.item).parent(".sortable").data("status-id");
         var task_id = jQuery_2(ui.item).data("task-id");
         jQuery_2.ajax({
             url: url,
             method: 'POST',
             data: { status_id: status_id, task_id: task_id, },
             success: function(response){ }
         });
    },*/
    update: function(e, ui) {
        var status_id = jQuery_2(ui.item).parent(".sortable").data("status-id");
        var task_id = jQuery_2(ui.item).data("task-id");
        //var order_id = jQuery_2(ui.item).index();
        var order_id = [];

        $("#sort"+status_id+" li").each(function(index) {
            order_id.push($(this).attr('data-task-id'));
        });

        jQuery_2.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: { status_id: status_id, task_id: task_id, order_id: order_id, },
            success: function(response){ }
        });
    }

 }).disableSelection();
 } );
```

Comment: Please add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did that Use event handler to capture the sort event and then get the sorted values through ToArray function and loop through the values and assign to array. This array then you can pass to Ajax post

```
    var $sortableList = $("#sortable");

var sortEventHandler = function(event, ui){
    var sortedIDs = $( "#sortable" ).sortable( "toArray" );
                var listValues = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < sortedIDs.length; i++) {

                listValues.push(sortedIDs[i]);
      }
            console.log(listValues);
};

$sortableList.sortable({
    stop: sortEventHandler
});

$sortableList.on("sortchange", sortEventHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery_2( function() {
 var url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>planner/Planner/edit_status/';
 jQuery_2('ul[id^="sort"]').sortable({
     connectWith: ".sortable",
     /*receive: function (e, ui) {
         var status_id = jQuery_2(ui.item).parent(".sortable").data("status-id");
         var task_id = jQuery_2(ui.item).data("task-id");
         jQuery_2.ajax({
             url: url,
             method: 'POST',
             data: { status_id: status_id, task_id: task_id, },
             success: function(response){ }
         });
    },*/
    update: function(e, ui) {
        var status_id = jQuery_2(ui.item).parent(".sortable").data("status-id");
        var task_id = jQuery_2(ui.item).data("task-id");
        //var order_id = jQuery_2(ui.item).index();
        var order_id = [];

        $("#sort"+status_id+" li").each(function(index) {
            order_id.push($(this).attr('data-task-id'));
        });

        jQuery_2.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: { status_id: status_id, task_id: task_id, order_id: order_id, },
            success: function(response){ }
        });
    }

 }).disableSelection();
 } );
```