# Dropzone.js drag-and-drop re-ordering of queue with jQuery sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone with autoProcessQueue: false to give the user a chance to remove files/etc.

Ideally, what I would like to allow is drag-n-drop reordering of the queue...so that if a user selects 10 images and drags them into the dropzone, they can then be ordered with the mouse.

So far, I have applied jQuerys `sortable()` to .dz-preview elements (.dz-preview is the div used in dropzone to display each image to be uploaded).

It works great insofar as it changes the display order of the .dz-preview elements...but they still upload in the exact order that they were initially added to the queue.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am newbie in script languages, I have scenario same as your, in my case I also want to re-ordering the image, but I dont know how it can do? can you suggest what way I should go? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is actually about `jQuery.sortable()`
You need to define `stop()` function for `sortable()`. From there you can get an order of elements and inject it to some hidden field in your form which will then be sent to server with rest of the fields.
Here is an example:[Get order of list items in a jQuery Sortable list after resort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320194/get-order-of-list-items-in-a-jquery-sortable-list-after-resort)